# How to monitor display state of an application window in Windows 7?

Tags: java-native-interface, jna

I need to monitor the display state of any application window in Windows7. I am trying to find out if any application window (based on the process id) is in minimized/maximized/normal state.

I am using JNA 4.2.1, Java 8 update72 on Windows 7 Enterprise.
Any pointers will be very helpful. Thanks in advance to all.

A sample code I tried is given below.

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HOOKPROC;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HOOKPROC proc = new HOOKPROC() {
            public User32.LRESULT callWndRetProc(int nCode, User32.WPARAM wParam, User32.LPARAM lParam) {
                            System.out.println("Recieved window event");
                return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(null, nCode, wParam, lParam);
            }
        };
        User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(12, proc, null, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easily done.  From MSDN:

> If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a
>   thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point
>   to a hook procedure in a DLL. Otherwise, lpfn can point to a hook
>   procedure in the code associated with the current process.

JNA dynamically generates small bits of code that call back into Java and it uses these to provide native function pointers for Java-based functions.  However, this code assumes that you already have a JVM up and running, and because they are dynamically generated, they *do not* live in a DLL.

The callback function to `SetWindowsHookEx` *must* be DLL-resident if not in the same thread as the target window.  In order to work with a JVM, that DLL-resident callback function would have to be responsible for launching the JVM if not already running.  JNA has some support for DLL-resident callbacks, but unfortunately does not implement any of the JVM launching support you'd need to make it actually work.

Comment: Is there any other method from User32 or other dll which can be used to get the current window state?

Comment: That's perhaps a question better asked in a w32 API forum.